# Can you compile a document from an Excel spreadsheet with LaTeX or similar software?

Tags: excel, latex

For my work, we compile documents that always have the same structure and it's very time intensive to make them in Word.

What I'm wondering is whether it would be possible to use an Excel spreadsheet to compile these documents automatically with a software like LaTeX (I'm open to use other software as well, I don't have experience with LaTeX yet).

What I want to be able to include: Image, Name, email, some other info, a table

[image: (see picture)]

So what I would like to do: create a spreadsheet with columns for all the various entries (Name, email, etc.) and compile a document from the info in the spreadsheet with a predefined structure/format. I'm not sure how the image would work, perhaps with a folder path?

Is this even possible? Is LaTeX the right tool or should I look elsewhere?

I also use Google docs a lot so if that's something that can be done with Google Sheets and Docs, that would also be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using **Microsoft Access**? It has a lot of built in features to help do this sort of thing - you can store the data there (like an excel spreadsheet), and create forms linked to the data / generate reports in the same application.

Alternatively in Word - you mention it being time intensive to create the same structured document, but are you using **Word templates**? (create your own structure, then you can make documents based off that each time). And/or you could perhaps **mail merge** the data across from Excel?

I only have a little experience with LaTeX, and while it's a brilliant tool it might be easier to try these 2 options if you are already used to the Office software :) Perhaps someone else will be able to give a nice easy LaTeX solution though!

---

P.S. you could try something like this http://hubpages.com/technology/IncludePicture   for mail merging images  (shift right click and 'copy as path' to get the full path of the image on your computer)

Answer (score 0):

Try the package excel2latex.
Maybe this can help you with generating latex code

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer but you can actually do this with Google Docs/Sheets and Ultradox (not sure about the image though).

I was also curious about alternatives with LaTeX but I haven't find anything relevant until now.